# Bootstrap / Vue.js - Collapse

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs2, bootstrap-5

I'm working with Bootstrap 5.1 or 4.6 (it's not working on either version) and Vue.js 2.

I need the following functionality: I want to click a button with a collapse function.

Now I have the following code in my first Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <!-- Menu class for first process -->
  <div class="row mt-5 mb-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <!-- collapse -->
    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-block d-grid" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
      <h4 class="text left font-weight-normal">
        <span class="ml-3">Collapse 1</span>
      </h4>
    </a>
  </div>
    <collapseThis/>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import collapseThis from './collapseThis.vue'

export default {
  name: 'collapse1',
  components: {
    collapseThis,
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

In my second Vue component I have this code:

```html
<template>
 <div class="collapse" id="collapse"> Some code in here </div>
</template>

<!-- also with export default and style - but it's not really relevant in here -->
```

My main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

//Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

When I click on my button it will not open - could someone please help me?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 and 5 are quite different. Please decide which version you want to use

Comment: Why are you importing BootstrapVue and then using native bootstrap syntax, instead of the BootstrapVue components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the correct target id. The trigger is referencing `collapse1`...

```
<template>
 <div class="collapse" id="collapse1"> Some code in here </div>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/555vK6RrNi)